# HTML-CSS design issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Following is CSS code

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Brand listing div -->
    <div class="custom-prod-brand col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-10" style="margin-top:11px;margin-left:20px;height:400px;">

    </div>

    <!-- Brand listing div end -->

    <!-- Product display listing -->
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-10 col-sm-8 custom-prod-display-class" style="background-color:white;margin-top:11px;margin-left:15px;">
        <!-- Product display div -->

        <!-- Product display div end -->
    </div>
    <!-- Product display listing end -->

      <div class="filter-display-div col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-10" style="margin-top:11px;margin-left:20px;height:400px;">

      </div>

</div>
```

I need "filter display div" below "brand display div".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried nesting the columns/rows? Like so:

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="col4">
 // menu container

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col12">
    // Brand display
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col12">
    // Filter Display
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>

 <div class="col8">
  // product display div
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanx it worked.......